# Leaflet fitBounds issue on mobile/small viewport

Tags: leaflet

I've been running into some odd issues with Leaflet's fitBounds method that only seem to occur when I test it in a mobile-sized browser window (either on a mobile device or a desktop). I am giving fitBounds a southwest corner and a northeast corner corresponding to two markers. On a full-sized screen it works fine; the map recenters between the two at an appropriate zoom level (you can see both). But on a small screen with portrait orientation, the map center seems to be slightly east of the center between the two markers, and the markers are each slightly out of the window. If I drag-pan the map the slightest bit, it suddenly jumps east, seemingly recentering on the proper centerpoint between the two markers.

Here is my code for this:

```
var bounds = L.latLngBounds([coordLats[0], coordLons[0]], [coordLats[1], coordLons[1]]);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
fixZoom();

function fixZoom(){
    var z = map.getZoom()
    z = z > 18 ? 18 : z; //don't go beyond max zoom!
    map.setZoom(z);
};
```

`coordLats` and `coordLongs` are arrays with the two markers' latitudes and longitudes respectively, ordered least to greatest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use this crude maxZoom hack. There is an option in L.TileLayer to set the max zoom.

```
L.tileLayer('http://tiles.lyrk.org/lr/{z}/{x}/{y}', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

In addition to that make sure that you include a proper viewport. If you don't provide that, Leaflet may have some unwanted behavior.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```